# What is the difference between sklearn.cross_validation and sklearn.model_estimation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to know the difference between importing `sklearn.model_estimation` and `sklearn.cross_validation` when I run Python code for linear regression.

I found out that `sklearn.model_estimation` calls a method called `next(ShuffleSplit().split(X, y))` and `sklearn.cross_validation` calls a method called `next(iter(ShuffleSplit(n_samples)))` but I am still in darkness as to what is the difference between what these two methods actually perform.

Looking for help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`cross_validation` is an older package used previously in scikit. `model_selection` is newer replacement of the `cross_validation` (and some others too). It has some structural changes in the classes defined in it.

So same class which was previously in `cross_validation` is now present in `model_selection` but with changed behaviour (input params, output type, attributes etc).

So you should always use classes from `model_selection`.